# ckeditor 404 not found error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter, ckeditor

I followed the installation and integration guide on ckeditor's site but there are still errors showing up, please help. I am using codeigniter.

these are the errors:

```
GET http://dev.website.com/config.js?t=D08E 404 (Not Found) 
GET http://dev.website.com/skins/moono/editor.css?t=D08E 404 (Not Found) 
GET http://dev.website.com/lang/en.js?t=D08E 404 (Not Found) 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
```

Comment: check if your config.js open in browser, and whether is formatted correctly. You might put the code here to show us, so we can more advise

Comment: None of these files exist. More than likely they're in a folder called 'ckeditor' as this is how it's downloaded. Try updating your URLs to `http://dev.website.com/ckeditor/...` of where ever you uploaded the files to.